# Mesh shrinks to small size when rendering, but in viewport, it's normal

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, mesh, 3d-view, transforms

I have a pretty large set of meshes. When in View port, render mode, or material mode, it looks great. But when I go to render image, all of the meshes get scattered and drastically changes scales (individual object shrink to varying sizes.) Almost like the transforms of every object get reset or break when executing a render. Why is this? ( I have tried Apply All Transforms)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following another post, I had a single keyframe somewhere (either on one mesh or all meshes) at the beginning of the timeline. Once I deleted that keyframe, problem solved.